# Render and Print HTML to non-default printer

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I have a C# WPF .NET 4.6 program that creates HTML files and I would like to print them automatically (without dialog) with a known, non-default printer. Of course this includes rendering the HTML first. Since the program creates these files, the HTML data can come from a `MemoryStream`, `FileStream`, or directly from string.

The program has settings that allows the user to specify which printer to print to in advance, using `System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters`, as each file may require a different printer. At printing time, the printer's name is known, but will likely be different from the Windows default printer.

I have researched a lot of other projects, but they do not seem to account for the printer being different from the default. Changing the default printer would be anti-social and would cause a world of threading-related pain. This seems to be the #1 accepted solution, though cannot be the best solution??

---

Research and solutions looked at:

[Printing the contents of a WPF WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298969/printing-the-contents-of-a-wpf-webbrowser) and [Silently print HTML from WPF WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23011397/silently-print-html-from-wpf-webbrowser/33824652#33824652) and 
[corresponding MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/64e48f1b-ff5c-45cf-8dac-5b55f0d09928/wpf-webbrowser-control-how-to-print-html-content?forum=wpf) [forum discussions](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/63ae5345-b2ca-45a9-9113-0ddc43e9925b/print-functionality-dialog-less-using-wpf-webbrowser-control?forum=wpf)
are insufficient as the COM [ExecWB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752117(v=vs.85).aspx) function only prints to the default printer (?)

The [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0wes9a3(v=vs.110).aspx) only uses the Print() command on the `WebBrowser`, which again uses the default printer.

So I went down the route of trying to change the printer options. [Programmatically changing the destination printer for a WinForms WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675430/programmatically-changing-the-destination-printer-for-a-winforms-webbrowser-cont) was asked, but has a rather unsatisfactory answer, as it has a broken link, and I don't know what external programs the running computer has, so I cannot guarantee Adobe, OpenOffice, etc. OP mentioned that they parsed the ActiveX COM without going into detail. Sounds tricky.

Perhaps I could gleam something from writing to a RichTextBox like [this project](http://www.itwriting.com/htmleditor/) does, and hide the box?

I thought [Silent print HTML file in C# using WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889315/silent-print-html-file-in-c-sharp-using-wpf) is on a good path, however the original post has hard-coded numbers for screen dimensions‽ and OP mentioned that the printer cut off the document. The accepted (and bountied) answer again use the ExecWB default printer settings method.

[execCommand("Print", false, IDon'tUnderstandThisArgument)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974996/execcommandprint-false-idontunderstandthisargument) also showed promise, as its answer was an updated [MSDN answer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.defaultpagesettings(v=vs.110).aspx), but the filestream sent to the printer does not allow HTML, nor does the `DocumentStream` from `WebBrowser` appear to work (the printer prints a single blank page).

[How do I programatically change printer settings with the WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714507/how-do-i-programatically-change-printer-settings-with-the-webbrowser-control) has very similar requirements to me, except changes the registry as a solution.

Other than researching how others have done it, I also tried printing the WPF `WebBrowser` directly as it is a `Visual` control:

```
    public static bool Print(string printer, Visual objToPrint)
    {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(printer))
      {
        return false;
      }

      var dlg = new PrintDialog
      {
        PrintQueue = new PrintServer().GetPrintQueue(printer)
      };

      dlg.PrintTicket.CopyCount = 1;
      dlg.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Portrait;
      dlg.PrintTicket.PagesPerSheet = 1;

      dlg.PrintVisual(objToPrint, "Print description");
      return true;
    }
```

however this does not print anything (because the `WebBrowser` is not visible?).
And tried a `PrintDocument` as the updated [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.defaultpagesettings(v=vs.110).aspx) suggested:

```
    public static async Task<bool> PrintHTMLAsync(string printer, string html)
    {
      bool result;
      using (var webBrowser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser())
      {
        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += ((sender, e) => browserReadySemaphore.Release());
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);
        webBrowser.DocumentStream = new MemoryStream(buffer);

        // Wait until the page loads.
        await browserReadySemaphore.WaitAsync();

        try
        {
          using (PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument())
          {
            pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printer;
            pd.PrinterSettings.Collate = false;
            pd.PrinterSettings.Copies = 1;
            pd.PrinterSettings.FromPage = 1;
            pd.PrinterSettings.ToPage = 1;
            pd.Print();
            result = true;
          }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          result = false;
          Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        return result;
      }
    }
```

with no joy.

I've also used the PRINT DOS command:

```
public static string PerformSilentPrinting(string fileName, string printerName)
{
  try
  {
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName)
    {
      Arguments = string.Format("/C PRINT /D:\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", printerName, fileName),
      FileName = "cmd.exe",
      RedirectStandardOutput = true,
      UseShellExecute = false,
      WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    };

    // Will execute the batch file with the provided arguments
    Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);

    // Reads the output        
    return process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    return ex.ToString();
  }
}
```

but the print command seems to only accept text files.

Comment: in System.Printing, to print multiples pages needs to use [DocumentPaginator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107880/wpf-fixeddocument-pagination)

Answer (score 2):

The best solution i found was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889315/silent-print-html-file-in-c-sharp-using-wpf)

This takes care of printing silently. However that doesn't allow you to change from the default printer. So as a workaround, you can set the default printer to the printer you'd like to use, and then switch back once you're done printing.

I'll be something like this:

```
protected static class PrinterSetter
    {
        [DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool SetDefaultPrinter(string Name);
    }
```

then in the code referenced in the link above you can add:

```
if (wb != null)
            {
                PrinterSettings settings = new PrinterSettings();
                string defaultPrinter = settings.PrinterName;

                Printer.SetDefaultPrinter("Microsoft Print to PDF");

                wb.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, null, null);


                (new System.Action(() =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    Printer.SetDefaultPrinter(defaultPrinter);
                })).BeginInvoke(null, null);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** This solution works well if you only need to print one page of A4. However it will only print one page, and truncates anything past it.

---

In the end I went with a WinForms WebBrowser, copied the control into a Bitmap, and printed using `PrintDialog`, which is also in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public static class PrintUtility
{
  private static readonly SemaphoreSlim browserReadySemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0);

  // A4 dimensions.
  private const int DPI = 600;
  private const int WIDTH = (int)(8.3 * DPI);
  private const int HEIGHT = (int)(11.7 * DPI);

  public static void Print(this Image image, string printer, bool showDialog = false)
  {
    if (printer == null)
    {
      throw new ArgumentNullException("Printer cannot be null.", nameof(printer));
    }

    using (PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog())
    {
      using (PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument())
      {
        printDialog.Document = printDoc;
        printDialog.Document.DocumentName = "My Document";
        printDialog.Document.OriginAtMargins = false;
        printDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printer;

        printDoc.PrintPage += (sender, e) => 
        {
          // Draw to fill page
          e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Width, e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Height);

          // Draw to default margins
          // e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, e.MarginBounds);
        };

        bool doPrint = !showDialog;
        if (showDialog)
        {
          var result = printDialog.ShowDialog();
          doPrint = (result == DialogResult.OK);
        }

        if (doPrint)
        {
          printDoc.Print();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static async Task<bool> RenderAndPrintHTMLAsync(string html, string printer)
  {
    bool result = false;

    // Enable HTML5 etc. (assuming we're running IE9+)
    SetFeatureBrowserFeature("FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", 9000);

    // Force software rendering
    SetFeatureBrowserFeature("FEATURE_IVIEWOBJECTDRAW_DMLT9_WITH_GDI", 1);
    SetFeatureBrowserFeature("FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING", 0);

    using (var webBrowser = new WebBrowser())
    {
      webBrowser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
      webBrowser.Width = WIDTH;
      webBrowser.Height = HEIGHT;
      webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += ((s, e) => browserReadySemaphore.Release());
      webBrowser.LoadHTML(html);

      // Wait until the page loads.
      await browserReadySemaphore.WaitAsync();

      // Save the picture
      using (var bitmap = webBrowser.ToBitmap())
      {
        bitmap.Save("WebBrowser_Bitmap.bmp");
        Print(bitmap, printer);
        result = true;
      }
    }

    return result;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Make a Bitmap from the Control.
  /// Remember to dispose after.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="control"></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public static Bitmap ToBitmap(this Control control)
  {
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(control.Width, control.Height);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, control.Width, control.Height);
    control.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, control.Width, control.Height));
    return bitmap;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Required because of a bug where the WebBrowser only loads text once or not at all.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="webBrowser"></param>
  /// <param name="htmlToLoad"></param>
  /// <remarks>
  /// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362591/how-to-display-the-string-html-contents-into-webbrowser-control/23736063#23736063
  /// </remarks>
  public static void LoadHTML(this WebBrowser webBrowser, string htmlToLoad)
  {
    webBrowser.Document.OpenNew(true);
    webBrowser.Document.Write(htmlToLoad);
    webBrowser.Refresh();
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// WebBrowser Feature Control
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="feature"></param>
  /// <param name="value"></param>
  /// <remarks>
  /// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697048/how-to-fix-a-opacity-bug-with-drawtobitmap-on-webbrowser-control/21828265#21828265
  /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330733(v=vs.85).aspx
  /// </remarks>
  private static void SetFeatureBrowserFeature(string feature, uint value)
  {
    if (LicenseManager.UsageMode != LicenseUsageMode.Runtime)
    {
      return;
    }

    var appName = Path.GetFileName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
    Registry.SetValue(
      @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\" + feature,
      appName, 
      value, 
      RegistryValueKind.DWord);
  }
}
```

Comment: exception when calling in formload > webbrowser document is null!!

Comment: document is null fix....  add this line  ``webBrowser.DocumentText = "fix Document is null"; ``   right above  ``webBrowser.DocumentCompleted  += ((s, e) ....``